# Lenovo laptop keep restarting

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop

I recently restarted my lenovo laptop, but it keeps stuck on restarting again and again saying

```
working on updates 0% 
 Your pc will restart several times
```

Laptop is stuck in a loop here. I tried to access repair settings by switching on and off for several times, but nothing appeared. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: At what stage exactly does the boot process stop? Do you see the Lenovo Splash Screen? Are you able to enter the UEFI setup? What model do you got? Have you triggered a firmware update, or did the error appear out of nothing?

Comment: It may have encountered a disk error (logical or hardware).  See if you can shut right down, and then get the repair menu from startup (not restart)

Comment: I can see the Lenovo splash screen and then appears a command line window or something like that for a little amount of time(it suddenly disappears). Then above message shows and keep restarting again. I didnt do anything special before happening this.

Comment: I also had the missing important updates notification in windows taskbar